# jboss jmx console login

Tags: jboss

I am using JBoss 4.x application server. I am trying to login to the JMX console which requires authentication.
I am providing username and password as "admin" but still it gives as HTTP 401.

Following entry is present in my jmx-console-users.properties file

```
# A sample users.properties file for use with the UsersRolesLoginModule admin=JBossAdmin.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the last part of this line is actually a line by itself:

```
# A sample users.properties file for use with the UsersRolesLoginModule 
admin=JBossAdmin
```

If that's the case, then the username is `admin` and the password is `JBossAdmin` . If not, it means the file doesn't contains any username/password. Just create a line similar to the one I mentioned above. Also, *please* promise me that you'll not leave `admin` as password.